# Can't find favicon in web page source

Tags: html, css, favicon

Maybe a stupid question, but for the life of me I can't find a reference to the favicon "ico" file on this website:

http://www.fitnessutah.com/

They obviously have one because it displays in the browser tab/window. I've tried Chrome developer tools, Network tab which shows all images on a page -- but no favicon there either. Where is it hiding?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It does seem to be being pulled in differently, but it is typically always in the default location - which this one is as well.

http://www.fitnessutah.com/favicon.ico

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways to specify the favicon for a website:

1) Give a `link` to the favicon

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/somepath/favicon.png" />
```

2) Put it in a prefefined URL, this is relative to the server root. So in this case will be http://www.fitnessutah.com/favicon.ico

This website seems to be using the second method so you will find the favicon in that link.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to add a `link` element with your favicon image for it to appear on your website.

Quote:
A second method for specifying a favicon relies on using a predefined URI to identify the image: "/favicon", which is relative to the server root.

Source:
http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Answer (score 5):

Further to Keir's and Carlos' answers - to spell it out - most browsers are programmed to also look for a favicon here:

```
http://yourwebsitename.com/favicon.ico
```

If the favicon image is named/stored as above, there is no need to mention it in the HTML code.

Therefore, if you are looking at a website and you can't find any reference to their favicon in the HTML source, just type the website's base URL in the browser address bar followed by `/favicon.ico`:

```
http://example.com/favicon.ico
```

Real-life example - try to find the favicon in the source code:

http://www.fuelly.com/favicon.ico

Answer (score 4):

Use Chrome Dev Tools Network tab.
Filter by favicon
reload the page with Shift+F5
You will get the icon regardless it was loaded with link or from default location

Comment: Can you explain that further? What does "it was loaded with link" mean?

Comment: @NicoHaase Please read the answers provided above. Everyone mentions there are two ways of using favicon.ico : with the [link] element, or with a default location.

Answer (score 0):

you will always find in chrome just enter **chrome://favicon/{domain.url}** in the address bar

for example

chrome://favicon/https://www.google.com/